# How to autocut cells after a specific number have been made and start a new row

Tags: php, html

I have a json file with an array of over 100 images

```
foreach($images as $image)
    {
                  $imagelink = $image['link'];
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td><img src=$imagelink></td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
    }
```

The problem is, this code prints out 1 image per line and the other one is below it.

How can I do it like the images are shown 4 in a line

Structure like this:

```
IMAGE   IMAGE   IMAGE   IMAGE
IMAGE   IMAGE   IMAGE   IMAGE
```

instead of

```
IMAGE
IMAGE
IMAGE
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
echo "<table>";

$col = 0;
$maxCols = 4;
foreach($images as $image)
{
    // first row, or we've already output the max number of images per row so start a new one
    if( $col % $maxCols == 0 ) {
        // we need to end a previously started row
        if( $col != 0 ) {
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "<tr>";
    }

    $imagelink = $image['link'];
    echo "<td><img src=$imagelink></td>";

    $col++;
}

// we didn't end the last row we started
if( $col != 0 ) echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You're welcome  :)  Make sure it all makes sense to you.  You'll probably end up doing things like this from time to time.  Also, maybe consider how you could improve it!